# WHERE date query returns "Date 'xxx' is not recognized" in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This query:

```
select * from weather_effects order by date desc limit 5;
```

Returns this:

[image]

Now I want to select by date

```
select * from weather_effects w where w.date = '2019-12-13';
```

But I got this error:

```
100040: Date '2010-10-03 04:32:52, 2011-01-10 08:41:37, 2011-01-13 21:05:23, 2011-01-24 21:16:55, 2011-02-19 04:16:59, 2011-05-01 06:41:41, 2011-05-08 02:15:23, 2011-05-11 05:44:18, 2011-07-17 04:52:19, 2011-11-19 03:46:59, 2011-11-30 04:14:01, 2011-12-23 23:41:42, 2011-12-26 05:23:42, 2012-02-03 07:32:03, 2012-02-03 08:05:14, 2012-04-24 01:08:08, 2012-05-01 01:42:03, 2012-06-03 06:43:34, 2012-07-29 07:52:24, 2012-08-02 02:40:10, 2012-09-01 03:15:01, 2012-12-19 12:43:06, 2012-12-24 22:08:29, 2013-01-01 08:43:20, 2013-01-12 10:19:29, 2013-02-25 06:33:35, 2013-03-20 06:37:46, 2013-03-31 06:44:18, 2013-04-03 11:09:52, 2013-04-20 05:20:52, 2013-04-22 14:47:54, 2013-04-27 03:25:01, 2013-05-04 05:47:48, 2013-05-26 13:15:51, 2013-06-24 03:34:11, 2013-06-27 03:47:52, 2013-06-28 04:04:11, 2013-07-08 03:12:15, 2013-07-10 04:43:07, 2013-07-22 04:38:48, 2013-07-25 19:58:43, 2013-07-29 04:40:02, 2013-08-18 02:37:00, 2013-09-11 07:52:43, 2013-09-23 06:41:21, 2013-09-30 04:39:22, 2013-10-05 07:00:22, 2013-12-24 09:53:12, 2013-12-29 04:23:24, 2013-12-29 06:24:32, 2014-02-07 11:40:35, 2014-02-15 05:57:23' is not recognized
```

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either:

```
where w.date::date = '2019-12-13'::date
```

Or:

```
where w.date >= '2019-12-13'::date and
      w.date < '2019-12-14'::date
```

Comment: 1st suggestion: got error 100040: Date '2012-03-11 15:10:01, 2012-11-21 18:36:09, 2014-08-08 16:01:40, 2015-06-19 16:39:08, 2015-07-03 06:29:20, 2016-05-18 11:42:09, 2016-11-06 20:02:40, 2018-12-07 03:08:18' is not recognized

Comment: 2nd suggestion: got error 100040: Date '2010-10-03 04:32:52, 2011-01-10 08:41:37, 2011-01-13 21:05:23, 2011-01-24 21:16:55, 2011-02-19 04:16:59, 2011-05-01 06:41:41, 2011-05-08 02:15:23, 2011-05-11 05:44:18, 2011-07-17 04:52:19, 2011-11-19 03:46:59, 2011-11-30 04:14:01, 2011-12-23 23:41:42, 2011-12-26 05:23:42, 2012-02-03 07:32:03, 2012-02-03 08:05:14, 2012-04-24 01:08:08, 2012-05-01 01:42:03, 2012-06-03 06:43:34, 2012-07-29 07:52:24, 2012-08-02 02:40:10, 2012-09-01 03:15:01, 2012-12-19 12:43:06, 2012-12-24 22:08:29, 2013-01-01 08:43:20, 2013-01-12 10:19:29, ... is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify the data type of the field "DATE" in that table?  It looks like you've got some long string somewhere in your table that are not only NOT dates, but appear to be timestamps...and a string of them.

Try something like this:

```
select * from weather_effects where TRY_TO_DATE("DATE") = '2019-12-13'::DATE;
```